# linux: can `top` show vCPU utilization inside of VM

Tags: multithreading, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I have a single VM (qemu/kvm) running a multi-threaded network application. The VM is configured with a number of vCPUs, the host CPU has 32 cores (64 with hyper threading enabled).

When I run `top -H`(i.e. show individual threads including vCPUs) on the host, it always reports vCPU utilization as 99.9% even when the application in VM is not processing any packets. Is `top` even supposed to VM-internal threads/cpu utilization?